# Form input group append prepend - is there an missing style? (BS4)

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

I wonder how to implement Bootstrap4 input group label between two input field. There are "prepend" and "append" styles, but in this case an ... don't know how to name it ... "center" style is needed. Am I missing something?

[image]

The corners of the element should not be rounded - this is a visual requirement. We must solve the problem entire using only bs4 pre-defined classes and styles, no local style="..." element is enabled. Know anybody the solution? Thanks!

```html
        

<div class="form-group col-6">
   <div class="input-group">
     <div class="input-group-prepend">
       <span class="input-group-text">Date interval:</span>
     </div>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dateFrom" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" value="2020-05-19">
     <span class="input-group-text">-</span>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dateTo" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" value="2020-06-19">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap provides border *classes*.

What is causing the rounded edges is a CSS property called `border-radius`.

The Bootstrap border classes most relevant to you would be the following:

1. `rounded-left` (rounds left side corners)
2. `rounded-0` (Equal to `border-radius: 0px;` - i.e. no rounded corners)
3. `rounded-right` (rounds right side corners)

All you need to do is add those classes to the elements so that it fits your desired needs.

More about Bootstrap border classes [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/).

Snippet Example:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group col-10">
   <div class="input-group">
     <div class="input-group-prepend">
       <span class="input-group-text rounded-left">Date interval:</span>
     </div>
     <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" name="dateFrom" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" value="2020-05-19">
     <span class="input-group-text rounded-0">-</span>
     <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-right" name="dateTo" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" value="2020-06-19">
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen Example [here](https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/JjGEJBm).

Comment: Oo thanks! I was searching for an input-group-* class name.